# Xamarin studio IDE to connect with networked MAC?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Please help on the below queries.. i am also trying to Google the question to the find answers.

1. Is it possible to connect Networked MAC  from Xamarin studio IDE  without using visual studio  to build the IOS Application ? using windows..
2. If Yes , Please help in my finding the right tutorials.
3. New to xamarin and mobile environment.

Please ignore if it repeated question, sorry for it.

Thanks,
Advika

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  However, you cannot do iOS Development on Xamarin Studio on Windows.  For iOS Development on Windows, you need Visual Studio.  Xamarin Sudio supports iOS development on a mac.  Given this, I'm not sure why you'd want to connect Xamarin Studio to a mac.

Comment: Thanks you @harsimranb  for the reply , We are started setup environment to build the ios application in the windows environment,  1) we install Xamarin studio and i don't find any  options like "IOS - ipad, Iphone"  ... From your last comment it seems i need visual studio to develop IOS application in windows Environment .. Thank you

Comment: Sure thing.  I'll post my comment as the answer. Remember to mark it as the answer if it helped you. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking. However, you cannot do iOS Development on Xamarin Studio on Windows. For iOS Development on Windows, you need Visual Studio. Xamarin Sudio supports iOS development on a mac. Given this, I'm not sure why you'd want to connect Xamarin Studio to a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Using ***Mac build Host*** you can do but you'll need the networked mac for developing and debugging too.

Using ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** using which you can ***debug,develop and deploy*** the app completely in windows ***without the help of any Apple system*** but to sign and release the app to appstore you will need Apple System though